# Add few line with in the middle of a file

Tags: sed

I want to add few in a file. Is it possible to use sed?

```
original file
test1
test2
test3
```

Expected output after adding the new line

```
test1

#
testing123
#

test3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using "while/read" instead of "sed", this is one solution:

```
[~]$ cat original.txt
test1
test2
test3

[~]$ cat new_content.txt

#
testing123
#
```

Then, process both files with the following script:

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
        if [[ $line =~ ^test2.*$ ]]
        then
                cat new_content.txt
        else
                echo "$line"
        fi
done < original.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '2 i\
\
#
2 a\
#\

' YourFile
```

- Arbitrary take the line 2 as middle (not easy to count or take *middle* in posix sed)
- `i`for insert (before)
- `a` for append (after)